# App crash on ios 5 after including google map sdk 1.7

Tags: google-maps, ios5, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have included google map sdk 1.7 in my project that runs on ios5.1 too. After integrating google sdk app is crashing on ios5.1. I know that google map sdk version >=1.5 supports ios6 and above. 
Is there a way to conditionally include the google map sdk. i.e. the sdk will only load if app is running ios6 or above. else I would like to take the user to the browser.

I am getting the following error on ios5

yld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityViewController
    Referenced from: /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/EC6760CC-D272-4949-A5BA-6AFB8B0C1A8F/HM.app/HM
    Expected in:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDK s/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

Comment: try macro to include headers of specific libray may resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can change xcode project settings.

[Read More:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

You can set the google framework in project settings as optional.
Then check for ios5 while `#import or #include` the google sdk. 
Don't import for ios 5 It will only for iOS6 and greater.